# Add class="current" to the parent menu when it's child has class="active"

Tags: php, css

I apparently have no idea of how to add class="current" to the `<li> tag` of the parent menu when it's `<li> tag` has a `class="active"`. I tried using jQuery to implement this, but It does not work since the page is reloaded when clicking on it. So I simply added a field called `name` into the database to use as a parameter. Bellowing is my PHP code:

```
echo '<ul>';
    $main_menu = model::getMainMenu();
       foreach($main_menus as $menu){
            echo '<li class="dropdown">
            <a href=?page='.$menu['name'].'&m=1 class='.(($_GET['page'] == $menu['name'])?'current':'').'>'.$menu['title'].'</a>';
            $sub_menus = model::getSubMenu($menu['id']);
            if( $sub_menus != '' ){
              echo '<ul>';
              foreach($sub_menus as $sub){
                echo '<li><a href=?page='.$sub['name'].' class='.(($_GET['page']==$sub['name'])?'current':'').'>'.ucwords( $sub['title'] ).'</a></li>';
              }
             echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
    }
</ul>
```

I can only detect which sub page or page is currently active by comparing the `$_GET['page'] and the $sub['name']` (my url structure is simply like this `index.php?page=home`). However, I have no idea how to detect the parent menu when its child is currently selected.

I uploaded the page [here](http://pio.comze.com)

Comment: This is a client-side issue. Please show the resulting HTML, not your server code.

Comment: i uploaded here http://pio.comze.com

Comment: "Here" may disappear any time. Better to edit your question and put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code below. Not sure if it is completely correct, but idea should be clear from it.
Basically  - you can collect all LIs html into a variable and set a flag to tru if one of LIs is active. And than echo everything taking into account flag variable state.

```
echo '<ul>';
    $main_menu = model::getMainMenu();
       foreach($main_menus as $menu) {                
            $sub_menus = model::getSubMenu($menu['id']);
            $lis = "";
            $hasCurrent = false;
            if($sub_menus != '') {
                foreach($sub_menus as $sub) {
                    $lis .= '<li><a href=?page='.$sub['name'].' class='.(($_GET['page']==$sub['name'])?'current':'').'>'.ucwords( $sub['title'] ).'</a></li>';
                        if($_GET['page']==$sub['name']) {
                            $hasCurrent = true;
                        }
                }
                echo '<li class="dropdown ' . $hasCurrent ? 'active' : '' . '">
                      <a href=?page='.$menu['name'].'&m=1 class='.(($_GET['page'] == $menu['name'])?'current':'').'>'.$menu['title'].'</a>';
                if($lis != '') {
                    echo '<ul>';
                    echo $lis;
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            }
            echo '</li>';
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: while setting the class via javascript and loading the new content dynamically via ajax would be certainly more elegant, this is the easiest way to do it serverside - and it's good advice for newer php programmer to remember that you can store html in variables and output it later in your script

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Give the 'active' tag an ID, rather than a class - as only one page can be active at a time (presumably).

Then use Javascript to walk through the DOM and find the parent element:

```
var active_elem = document.getElementById("active");
var parent_element = active_elem.parentElement.parentElement;
```

Then assign the class / ID or whatever it is you want to do.